# Where are github secrets stored?

Tags: github, testdriven.io

[I'm on the CI part of the course](https://testdriven.io/courses/tdd-fastapi/continuous-integration/)

I'll start by saying all works well, and I could follow the process with ease. However, there is something that works, and I cannot figure out how. Let's take this part of the main.yml file:

```yaml
- name: Log in to GitHub Packages
  run: echo ${GITHUB_TOKEN} | docker login -u ${GITHUB_ACTOR} --password-stdin docker.pkg.github.com
  env:
    GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

I have these parameters like GITHUB_ACTOR and GITHUB_TOKEN, that I didn't define as any part of my code, or write into a panel inside GitHub.

Are they automatically filled in by GitHub?
If I change my token, will this code still work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is documented in "[Automatic token authentication](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication)"

> At the start of each workflow run, GitHub automatically creates a unique `GITHUB_TOKEN` secret to use in your workflow.
> You can use the `GITHUB_TOKEN` to authenticate in a workflow run.
>
> When you enable GitHub Actions, GitHub installs a GitHub App on your repository.
> The `GITHUB_TOKEN` secret is a GitHub App installation access token. You can use the installation access token to authenticate on behalf of the GitHub App installed on your repository. The token's permissions are limited to the repository that contains your workflow

You have [Default environment variables](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables#default-environment-variables), including:

> `GITHUB_ACTOR`: The name of the person or app that initiated the workflow.
> For example, `octocat`.

---

```yaml
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                          Updated Workflow                               |
|                                                                         |
| +----------------------+     +--------------------------------------+   |
| | main.yml             |     | GitHub                               |   |
| |                      |     |                                      |   |
| |                      |     | +---------+   +--------+  +--------+ |   |
| |                      |     | | Secrets |   | Tokens |  | Actors | |   |
| | - name: Log in to    |     | +---------+   +--------+  +--------+ |   |
| |   GitHub Packages    |     |                                      |   |
| |   run: echo          |<----| Automatically provided by GitHub     |   |
| |   ${GITHUB_TOKEN}    |     |                                      |   |
| |   | docker login     |     |                                      |   |
| |   -u ${GITHUB_ACTOR} |     |                                      |   |
| |   --password-stdin   |     |                                      |   |
| |   docker.pkg.github  |     |                                      |   |
| |   .com               |     |                                      |   |
| |   env:               |     |                                      |   |
| |   GITHUB_TOKEN:      |     |                                      |   |
| |   ${{ secrets        |     |                                      |   |
| |   .GITHUB_TOKEN }}   |     |                                      |   |
| +----------------------+     +--------------------------------------+   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+`
```

The `GITHUB_TOKEN` and other secrets are securely stored on GitHub's servers. Specifically, they are encrypted at rest and can only be accessed by GitHub Actions runners during the execution of the workflow. These secrets are decrypted in a secure environment, which is essential for safeguarding sensitive data used within your CI/CD processes.
See "[Using secrets in GitHub Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/using-secrets-in-github-actions)"

You can define and manage your own secrets in the repository settings under the "Secrets" section. Once set, these secrets are encrypted and cannot be seen or edited, only deleted or replaced.

Here is an example command using the GitHub CLI [`gh secret set`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_secret_set) to update a secret, which is then stored encrypted on GitHub's servers:

```bash
gh secret set GITHUB_TOKEN -b "new-token-value"
```

> If I change my token, will this code still work?

Yes, the code will continue to work if you change your token, as long as the new token has the necessary permissions.
The `GITHUB_TOKEN` reference in the `main.yml` file will automatically fetch the updated token from GitHub secrets.
The line `GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}` is structured to pull the current value of `GITHUB_TOKEN` from GitHub secrets each time the workflow runs. So, if you update the token in GitHub secrets, the new value will be used in subsequent workflow runs.

Comment: I think the question is "where" it is stored not "how"

Comment: @Arun I agree. I have edited the answer to add "where".